# Configuring tsconfig.json and eslint for a monorepo using Yarn workspaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tsconfig, yarn-workspaces

I'm using a Yarn workspace monorepo structure in a TypeScript React project:

```
packages
  admin
    package.json
  user
    package.json
package.json // Workspace Root. Sets "workspaces": ["packages/*"]
```

I'm strugling to set up `eslint` along-side TypeScript.

This is my current `.eslintrc.json` file:

[image]

But I'm not really sure on how many `.eslintrc` and `tsconfig.json` files do I need.

**OPTION #1**

Each package would handle its own `.eslintrc.json` and `typescript.json`

```
packages/
  admin/
    package.json
    .eslintrc.json
    tsconfig.json
  user/
    package.json
    .eslintrc.json
    tsconfig.json

package.json
```

**OPTION #2**

Have a root-leve `.eslintrc.json` and `tsconfig.json` and just do some extends and overrides (if necessary) for the inner packages.

```
packages/
  admin/
    package.json
    .eslintrc.json  // Some extends/overrides
    tsconfig.json   // Some extends/overrides
  user/
    package.json
    .eslintrc.json  // Some extends/overrides
    tsconfig.json   // Some extends/overrides

package.json
.eslintrc.json
tsconfig.json
```

Which of the 2 options should I follow? If I go with option 2, do I need any special config on the  `.eslintrc.json` and `tsconfig.json` for the `root` level?

Comment: Did you manage to make option 2 work? I'm trying but falling short.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second approach, but don't forget to mention the extension part in package `.eslintrc.json`

root `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  ...
}
```

package `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "../../.eslintrc.json" 
  ]
}
```